# JavaScript # regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use a regex expression in a switch statement. The below code works for a colon after some characters but the next line of code doesn't work for a hashtag and then some characters. Why? It also doesn't work for an ampersand.

```
case (this.temp[this.index].match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]:/) || {}).input: console.log("test"); break;

case (this.temp[this.index].match(/#[a-zA-Z0-9]/) || {}).input: console.log("Hello"); break;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Unfortunately, without providing the string that you are trying to match, there isn't really sufficient information in the question for the community to provide you with helpful guidance.  I would recommend reviewing [ask], and then looking at ways to improve this question in such a way that it invites useful answers for you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seem to work well but you speak of "some characters" actually in this 2 regex you match only **one** character because it's the default if you doesn't precise a quantifier, you can easly test/watch that with an online tool like regex101.

For somes characters you can use [a-zA-Z0-9]* (can have 0 to infinite) [a-zA-Z0-9]+ at least one ...

Comment: Could you add the value of the string this.temp[this.index] or equivalent and the switch clause for check ? That can be helpful ^^